# Symlink all files but copy certain extensions

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, cp, mirroring, ln

I'm wondering how I'd be able to symlink all the files in a dir structure and then also copy files of a certain extension in that dir. I'm basically symlinking all files within /foo/a,b,c to /bar/a,b,c and then copying over certain files with a certain extensions.

Comment: I am assuming this is linux?

Comment: Yes, sorry, in linux.

Comment: Were /foo/a /foo/b foo/c meant to be directories? In that you need the entire directory structure copied under /foo, symlink all files not of a certain ext (in tree /foo), and finally copy all files of a certain ext (in tree /foo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the /bar directory, to create all symlinks for everything but these extensions.

```
find ../foo/ -type f ! -name '*.txt' ! -name '*.baz' -exec ln -s '{}' \;
```

And then to copy all the extensions, same command for the most part.

```
find ../foo/ -type f \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.baz" \) -exec cp '{}' ./ \;
```

**Edit**: Copy entire directory structure, symlink some files, copy others. Wasn't sure if this was possible at first with a single command, but just learned some other handy tricks with find.

```
find foo/ -type d -printf "mkdir -vp 'bar/%p'\n" -o -type f ! -name "*.txt" ! -name "*.baz" -printf "ln -vs '../%p' 'bar/%p'\n" -o -type f \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.baz" \) -printf "cp -v %p bar/%p\n" | sh
mv bar/foo/* bar/ && rm -R bar/foo/
```

Only important thing to note is when making the symbolic link you give the actual path the links will take to relate to foo/. My example shows relative links when they are side by side (could also make absolute symbolic links as well).

Comment: Great job, that works wonders! Thanks for sharing the knowledge on find!! Good stuff..